# Why overlines do not count on Gomoku?

Tags: gomoku

*I understand that in Gomoku the overlines (lines of 6 or more) do not count for a victory in most tournament ruleset, but may count in casual play. Fine.*

**WHY** in Gomoku there is the rule of "overlines do not count"?

Is this a purely historical reason, like "this is the way", or it actually brings in some benefit to the game?

Answer (score 1):

Because the goal of the game is to place exactly 5 stones in a row. Having it limited to exactly 5 pieces means there is more strategy involved in also making sure you don't make a chain to long.

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gomoku.html

> In standard gomoku, rows of exactly five piece are required for a win, so if a row longer than five pieces (called an overline) is created, it does not count as a win. In free-style gomoku, overlines also count as wins.

Comment: Yeah but this is simply restating the rules, basically. Does requiring exactly 5 stones improve the game, over not doing it?

Comment: Your question just appears to ask why this is required and that is because the rules require it. As for the reason they decided to go with this that could be very much opinion based. However a quick answer could be because of the strategy involved is different when you have to get exactly 5 in a row. It would be possible to force your opponent to make a play in order to block them from winning that also blocks one of your possible win choices later by making the chain longer than 5 stones when it is complete.

Comment: Actually asked why that rule exists.

Comment: @o0'. You could ask that about any rule in any game and it can be a very hard question to answer unless the designers come out and say why,